# How to set the width of \multirow within \multicolumn to full table width

Tags: tables, multicolumn, multirow, width

I wish to have a multirowed-multicolumned text on the bottom of my table.

[image]

Where i put in explanatory text for superscripts in the table, as well as explain any abbreviations.

I can in a way force this just using multicolumn and manually breaking my text into many rows, but the text is then not justified, which I want.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\caption{Caption}}
\label{}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{ccccccccccccc}
          &                           &              &  & \multicolumn{9}{c}{A}                                                                                     \\ \cline{5-13} 
          &                           &              &  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1}                          &  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2}                            \\ \cline{5-8} \cline{10-13} 
C:DBE     & \textit{m/z} [M + Na]$^+$ & Compound$^e$ &  & Peaks & Isomers &      & Most abundant FA pair$^a$ &  & Peaks & Isomers &      & Most abundant FA pair$^a$   \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{5-8} \cline{10-13} 
C:DBE        & value                 &              &  &       &         &      &                           &  & 1     & 2       &      & thing/                   \\
\multicolumn{13}{l}{\multirow{}{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep\relax}{$^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns}}  

\end{tabular}%
}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I want the very long text to span the full width of the table. i tried setting width as \textwidth, but it ends up exactly similar to this.

Sorry if the image appears in the middle of the text I cant figure out how to move it.

Comment: why do you need it to be multirow?? if it is full width it can not be spanning rows in other columns. It just needs to be in a `\multicolumn` or simpler, put it after the table.

Comment: try to avoid `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%` resizing tables should only be a last resort (and even then avoid it)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle how do I put it after the table and at the same time "stick it" to the table - and keep the text the same size as the text in the table. As for the resize - the table needs to fit within an A4 page (standard for journals) - and I don't know how to do it otherwise...

Comment: just use a blank line after the end tabular and then place the text remove the resizebox so you can control the font size, then use `\small` or \footnotesize` or whatever font size works, using scaling and getting inconsistent fonts and rule widths makes it impossible to get reasonable output

Comment: Ah, thanks. Placing the text between \end{tabular} and \end{table} worked great. Didn't know I could do that. I can't figure out the sizeing without resize though, it becomes a mess with 13 columns. But I can live with using the resize.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need `\multicolumn` or `\multirow` here nor to scale the table to an arbitrary and inconsistent font size.

[image]

Just choose a smaller font size (`\scriptsize` here) and move the notes after the table.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\newcommand\hd[1]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htp]

\caption{Caption\label{zz}}

\scriptsize
\setlength\tabcolsep{1.9pt}
\begin{tabular}{@{}ccccccccccccc@{}}
          &                           &              &  & \multicolumn{9}{c@{}}{A}                                                                                     \\ \cline{5-13} 
          &                           &              &  & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1}                          &  & \multicolumn{4}{c@{}}{2}                            \\ \cline{5-8} \cline{10-13} 
C:DBE     & \textit{m/z} [M + Na]$^+$ & Compound$^e$ &  & Peaks & Isomers &      & \hd{Most abundant\\ FA pair$^a$} &  & Peaks & Isomers &      & \hd{Most abundant\\ FA pair$^a$}   \\
\cline{1-3} \cline{5-8} \cline{10-13} 
C:DBE        & value                 &              &  &       &         &      &                           &  & 1     & 2       &      & thing/                   \\
\end{tabular}

$^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns 



\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an attempt of putting in a MWE what David already said.
I used `adjustbox` instead of `\resizebox`. `ragged2e` is for `\justify`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{}
    \adjustbox{width=\textwidth}{
        \begin{tabular}{*{13}{c}}
                  &                           &              & & \multicolumn{9}{c}{A}                                                                                     \\ \cline{5-13}
                  &                           &              & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1}                                                                                                     &         & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2}                            \\ \cline{5-8} \cline{10-13}
            C:DBE & \textit{m/z} [M + Na]$^+$ & Compound$^e$ & & Peaks                                                                                                                     & Isomers &                                                                               & Most abundant FA pair$^a$ & & Peaks & Isomers & & Most abundant FA pair$^a$   \\ \cline{1-3} \cline{5-8} \cline{10-13}
            C:DBE & value                     &              & &                                                                                                                           &         &                                                                               &                           & & 1     & 2       & & thing/                   \\
        \end{tabular}%
    }
    \justify{\scriptsize
        a very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns a very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns a very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns a very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns a very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns a very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns a very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns a very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns a very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns a very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns
    }
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: er no I said don't resize tables!!! changing `\resizebox` to adjustbox isn't a change at all as `adjustbox` just calls `\resizebox` agaon and also you have omited teh `%` after `\adjustbox{width=\textwidth}{` and the syntax `\justify{\scriptsize       a very long text ...    }` is completely wrong and sets the small text on a large baseline, as your image shows.

Answer (score 2):

I think that probably you're after the functionality of `threeparttable` Other than that,  it is almost impossible to have 13 columns fitting the text width of  a4 paper, even playing with the fontsize and the value of `\tabcolsep`. So I suggest to use a `sidewaystable`. I added some æsthetic improvements such as the use of the rules from `booktabs` and two-line columnheads with `makecell`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx, rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}%[!htb]
\centering\small \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\setlength{\cmidrulekern}{0.25em}
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Caption}
\label{}
\begin{tabular}{*{13}{c}}
          & & & & \multicolumn{9}{c}{A} \\ \cmidrule[\heavyrulewidth]{5-13}
          & & & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{1} & & \multicolumn{4}{c}{2} \\ \cmidrule(lr){5-8} \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
C:DBE & \textit{m/z} [M + Na]$^+$ & Compound\tnote{e} & & Peaks & Isomers & & \thead{Most abundant\\ FA pair\tnote{a}} & & Peaks & Isomers & & \thead{Most abundant\\ FA pair\tnote{a}} \\ \cmidrule(lr){1-3} \cmidrule(lr){5-8} \cmidrule(lr){10-13}
C:DBE & value & & & & & & & & 1 & 2 & & thing/ \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]\footnotesize\smallskip
\item[a] very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns
    \item[e]very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns $^a$ very long text that spans 4-5 lines and all columns
\end{tablenotes}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]